# Arrays as object attributes in fortran - coarrays disabled?

Tags: oop, fortran, fortran90

I'm working with GNU gfortran (gfortran -v4.8.2), and I'm having trouble using arrays as object attributes. Here's what I mean:

```
type test_type
  real*8 test_array(10,20)
end type test_type

type (test_type) example_test_type
```

Later when I attempt to assign an element of test_array:

```
example_test_type%test_array[0,1] = 99
```

The compiler complains (fatal error):

**Fatal Error: Coarrays disabled at (1), use -fcoarray= to enable**

From what little I can find, coarrays are designed to facilitate support for parallel programming, which I am definitely not trying to do here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: With a question like this, my only comment is to buy [Metcalf & Reid](http://www.amazon.com/Fortran-90-Explained-Michael-Metcalf/dp/0198505582) and read it before moving any further with your programming.

Comment: Hardly necessary to buy Metcalf & Reid (useful as it is); reading the type declaration carefully might have brought enlightenment.

Comment: Perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features may help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong type of brackets / braces / parentheses (circle one) in this statement:

```
example_test_type%test_array[0,1] = 99
```

which should be

```
example_test_type%test_array(0,1) = 99
```

`[]` are used for specifying co-indices into co-arrays, hence the, to you, confusing error message.

Next you're going to have problems referencing element `(0,1)` of the array, since, by default, Fortran indexing begins at 1.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that appears to have fixed things. My question is, the compiler says that coarrays are not allowed unless I pass this -fcoarray flag. By changing this syntax, am I not still using coarrays? Why does the compiler not complain?

Comment: No, if you're not using `[]` for indexing expressions you're not using co-arrays whether or not you specify the co-array compilation option. Follow @KyleKanos' advice or search out some other up-to-date Fortran reference.